# Reading a file that has multiple lines and outputting that to a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlabel

I am reading from a file that will have tons of lines of text and I want my program to read all of the lines in that file and output them in the same format onto either a JLabel or anything that would work.

```
public String readSoldTo() {
        String file = "/Users/tylerbull/Documents/JUUL/Sold To/soldTo.txt";
        String data;

        try{

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(data);
                return data;

                }
              br.close();
              }catch(Exception e) {

              }
        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A JLabel is built to display one line of text. Yes you can jury-rig it to show more, but that's a kludge and can often cause future problems in your code. Instead I would suggest that you display your text in a JTextArea, and you can make it so that it **looks** like a JLabel by removing its border by making its background color null. If you add it to a JScrollPane though, you'll see scrollbars (if appropriate) and the scrollpane's border, which may be a problem. I would also make the JTextArea non-focusable and non-editable, again so that it acts more like a label and less like a text component that accepts user interaction.

Also JTextComponents, like JTextFields have mechanisms that allow you pass it a reader so that it can participate in the reading of the text file, preserving line breaks if desired. Please see its [read method API entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) for more on this. As always, take care to respect Swing threading rules, and do your text I/O in a background thread, and all Swing mutation calls on the Swing event thread.

Your code also worries me some:

- You seem to be ignoring exceptions
- You have two returns in your method above, and both return two vastly different bits of information.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextAreaAsLabel extends JPanel {
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 30;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 50;
    private static final Font TA_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 12);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);

    public TextAreaAsLabel() {
        // JButton and JPanel to open file chooser and get text
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new ReadTextAction("Read Text")));

        // change JTextArea's properties so it "looks" like a multi-lined JLabel
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setBackground(null);
        textArea.setBorder(null);
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(TA_FONT);

        // add components to *this* jpanel
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class ReadTextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ReadTextAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // create file chooser and limit it to selecting text files
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files", "txt");
            fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

            // display it as a dialog
            int choice = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(TextAreaAsLabel.this);
            if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                // get file, check if it exists, if it's not a directory
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                    // use a reader, pass into text area's read method
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
                        textArea.read(br, "Reading in text file");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextAreaAsLabel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with reading the data.  When I call that method in another class, it says it is null.  What would I need to have so when I call it in another method it will have all the data?

Comment: @TylerBull: see example code above. Your new problem is a completely unrelated problem and one that you'll have to debug. Look back into your code to see why you're getting null where you don't expect it. Use a debugger if need be.

Comment: I got it working.  I used a JTextArea and appended an array to display my text.  Thanks for your help.